# Reconnecting an iOS app to a paired BlueTooth device?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, ibeacon

As you know, after some period of inactivity, a Bluetooth device will disconnect from an iPhone. The user will then have to go back to Settings in order to reconnect the device.

1 - Is it possible for an iOS app (when it enters foreground) to force the reconnection to a paired Bluetooth device, without any user input?

2 - Is it possible to force the reconnection to a paired Bluetooth device, but during an app wake-up state from an iBeacon signal (matching UUID)?

Comment: I see you tagged this iBeacon, but did not mention that in the question.  To clarify, when you say BLE UUID do you mean a GATT Service UUID or an iBeacon Proximity UUID?

Comment: I meant an iBeacon Proximity UUID. I rewrote my 2nd question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use `CoreBluetooth` APIs to connect to a Bluetooth LE device without user input.  It doesn't have to be "paired" in the same way as a Bluetooth Classic device.  To do this, the Bluetooth LE device should expose a GATT Service UUID that the mobile app can recognize, and when it discovers this Service UUID, it can simply connect programatically.
2. When you use `CoreLocation` APIs to wake up your app based on iBeacon detections, the app is launched into the background temporarily.  You can send a local notification to the user to try to get the user to tap on it and bring the app to the foreground, but if the user does not, app background rules still apply.

Bringing together #1 and #2, you should understand the rules Apple places on using `CoreBluetooth` in the background.  See Apple's docs for [The bluetooth-central Background Execution Mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html).  It would be possible to make a connection in the background if you get the proper app permissions.

Comment: Thanks David! By the way, do you mean that my app, in order to make a connection in the background, should get a prior permission from the user (from a popup inside my app) or should it get a special app permission from Apple?

Comment: When you request the bluetooth-central permission in your iOS app's plist file, the user will be prompted to accept this permission when the user first launches the app.  The user must accept this permission for the app to be able to connect to the peripheral in the background.  The user will also be able to turn this permission on/off in the settings for the app.